# Python: CSV to JSON without Index

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to convert the last row of a CSV to a JSON file.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("names.csv")
df = df.tail(1)    
print(df)
df.to_json("names.json")
```

The output is correct, however it contains the row ID (3) which is not intended, example:

```
print(df)
    Name  Age  Weight
3  John   42      79

names.json
{"name":{"3":"John"},"Age":{"3":42},"Weight":{"3":79}}
```

I would expect something like:

```
{ "name":"John", "Age":42, "Weight":79 }
```

I have tried also `df.reset_index().to_json('names.json', orient='records')` from another post.

Comment: What does your original df looks like ? Could you include df.tail() ?

Comment: how about : `df.to_json(orient='records')` ?

Comment: Can you not select the last row directly and json that - eg: `df.iloc[-1].to_json()` - that way you're converting a series vs a one row dataframe...

Comment: Name  Age  Weight
3  John   42      79

Comment: @anky, great answer

Answer (score 0):

You can flatten the dicts:

```py
data = {"name": {"3": "John"}, "Age": {"3": 42}, "Weight": {"3": 79}}
result = {key: value for key, values in data.items() for value in values.values()}
print(result)
```

You get:

```py
{'name': 'John', 'Age': 42, 'Weight': 79}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use pandas [todict](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) method:

```
df.to_dict('records')
[{'Name': 'John', 'Age': 42, 'Weight': 79}]
```

if you are keen on just getting only the dict:

```
df.to_dict('records')[0]
{'Name': 'John', 'Age': 42, 'Weight': 79}
```